# installer software for macintosh?

Tags: macos, installation, osx-snow-leopard, osx-leopard

What installer software for macintosh would you recommend? It has to support leopard & snow leopard. Be easily scriptable and not expensive.

Thank you,

Nava

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OS X's built-in installer can be scripted, either via shell script (or any other executable) at particular stages of the install, or customized much more pervasively using JavaScript. Read the [Software Delivery Guide](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/SoftwareDistribution/Introduction/Introduction.html) for OS X.

Comment: It's not clear from the question what type of script control is needed, but Apple's installer package format (see "Managed Installs" under Barry's link) almost certainly supplies what you need: you can use a script to initiate and control the install, and also embed scripts in the package itself to control the installation in a variety of ways.  Also, PackageMaker is free as part of Xcode.

Answer (score 10):

Best answer is: don't.

The "Mac Way" is to provide just a .app that the user can drag into /Applications or ~/Applications.  The .app is really a directory that contains all the program's assets: code, properties, imagery, etc.

The only time you need to build an installer package is when you're modifying the system. In the Mac world, that's seldom the right answer.

Comment: It should be made clear that for the instances when it is needed, OS X has an installer system built-in, so third-party installers are even more of a bad idea.

Comment: unfortunately i need to script it, since i have to differentiate between systems. I would use the Installer Maker of Stuffit or VISE, but these are expensive packages and "overqualified" for my needs. I need something more simple

Comment: OSX installer doesn't have a concept of "uninstall". They just can't get anything right...

Comment: @Eugene - I have seen uninstallers, but for most things just trashing the .app is sufficient.

Comment: @Nava - what do you mean by "differentiate between systems", is this really something that the installer needs to do?

Comment: I have 2 executables: one for leopard and one for snow leopard. I'd like users to have a single installer, that can install one of these 2 versions, depending on target system. The package will contain both executables of course

Comment: @Eugene, there are uninstallers, especially for software, that disperse its components into multiple folders on the system. Adobe applications are good example. Most of mac applications are self-contained, so indeed trashing the .app wipes everything in most cases. Windows is a bit more complicated story, because you never know what the installer puts on your computer...

Comment: Yes, there are uninstallers, but they are not apple's. People must implement their own (we do). And users must remember to run them. First is a waste and a bit dangerous, second is unlikely.